# Unable to identify image using WebDriver as it gives null value

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have got null when I search for the src attribute of an image. Please resolve the element identification for the image.

My Selenium WebDriver code to identify the image src using WebDriver:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[contains(@class, 'image-section')]/img")
private WebElement getimage;

public String getImageSrc(){
    return  getimage.getAttribute("src");
}
```

I have the following exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element:
```

Comment: How do you think someone can help you with this infos? Your exception means that you aren't able to locate the interested element.

Comment: here is the HTML for the image: <div class="image-section">
    <div class="img-container">
    <img alt="Test Alternate text" src="/content/dam/kh-facebook-group-cover-
    photo-size.png">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your html:

```
<div class="image-section">
<div class="img-container">
<img alt="Test Alternate text" src="/content/dam/kh-facebook-group-cover- photo-size.png">
```

you could try this xpath in order to locate the element:

```
//div[@class='image-section']/div[@class='img-container']/img[@alt='Test Alternate text']
```

and after get the `"src"` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment below your question you can use any of this xpaths

```
//img[@alt='Test Alternate text']

//img[@alt='Test Alternate text' and @src='/content/dam/kh-facebook-group-cover- photo-size.png']
```

or

```
//div[@class='img-container']/img[@alt='Test Alternate text' and @src='/content/dam/kh-facebook-group-cover- photo-size.png']
```

Answer (score 0):

### Your HTML:

```
<div class="image-section">
<div class="img-container">
<img alt="Test Alternate text" src="/content/dam/kh-facebook-group-cover- photo-size.png">
```

### What's wrong:

- img tag is the second div tag

### Solve it:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[contains(@class, 'image-section')]//img")
private WebElement getimage;

public String getImageSrc(){
    return  getimage.getAttribute("src");
}
```